# How to launch a bat window from a batch file, and use a variable from the previous file?

Tags: batch-file, variables

I want to know how to use variables from another bat file, without using `call` as it only calls the file within the window. I want to know how to start another window a few times while using a variable set from the previous window. For example, this is `bat1.bat`:

```
@echo off
set /p value="Enter value:"
```

And let's say I have bat2.bat. I want to open another window for bat2.bat, but I would like to use `%value%` as a variable, which the user entered. How do I do this?

Comment: Oh go on then, I'll say it `Call`. Of course as with all things scripting there are more ways to skin a cat but for those you're going to have to provide real scenarios with genuine batch files, _(note the plural)_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is pretty easy, depending on what you want to achieve.

Typically in these cases you would use `call`, **BUT** you can pass the variable to a new window.

**bat1.cmd**

```
@echo off
set /p "var1=Please enter Variable :"
start bat2.cmd
pause
```

**bat2.cmd**

```
@echo off
echo This, %var1% came from bat1.cmd
pause
```

Comment: Oh wow, thanks for the help! I didn't think it would be that simple.